# How to recalculate columns and store new values in a same dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

The below link shows my initial data frame.

[image]

The inc_per column has wrong values in it. so I want to recalculate this and update data frame with new values in it. So I tried this code:

```
cars<- within(cars,cars$per_inc<- (cars$oldprice / cars$newprice)*100)
```

But it created unnecessary columns and I didn't get my desired output

My desired output can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please don't post code as images. You can present both code and output monospaced by indenting it with 4 spaces. You can edit your post using the button below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very easy use

```
cars$per_inc <-  (cars$oldprice / cars$newprice)*100
```

this will replace the current column values with new one.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.